# Keycloak admin client authHeader is null

Tags: java, keycloak, quarkus

I'm trying to create a new User in Keycloak with quarkus-keycloak-admin-client but it always says:
Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "authHeader" is null

```
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import org.keycloak.OAuth2Constants;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.KeycloakBuilder;
import org.keycloak.representations.idm.RoleRepresentation;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import java.util.List;

@ApplicationScoped
public class AuthenticationCrontrol {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationCrontrol.class);

    Keycloak keycloak;
    public AuthenticationCrontrol() {
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void initKeycloak() {
        keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl("http://localhost:8081/")
                .realm("master")
                .clientId("admin-cli")
                .username("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
                .build();
        LOG.info("Keycloak initialized");
    }

    public List<RoleRepresentation> getRoles() {
        return keycloak.realm("master").roles().list();
    }
}
```

this is my class

```
# OIDC Configuration
%test.quarkus.keycloak.devservices.enabled=true
%dev.quarkus.keycloak.devservices.enabled=true
%prod.quarkus.keycloak.devservices.enabled=false

# Keycloak Port
quarkus.keycloak.devservices.port=8081
%test.quarkus.keycloak.devservices.port=8181
%prod.quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://localhost:8543/realms/quarkus
quarkus.oidc.client-id=dolmetscher
quarkus.keycloak.devservices.grant.type=client
quarkus.oidc.application-type=hybrid
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=secret
quarkus.oidc.tls.verification=none
```

this is my application.properties

What am i missing??

Comment: Is this error reported in `initKeycloak` or when creating a new user ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
I was running on RESTEasy Classic but it seems you need RESTEasy Reactive.
After changing to it, it worked with no problem.

Comment: Great. Looks like there may have been a mix up of reactive and classic dependencies, if this problem was seen with RESTEasy Classic and non reactive Keycload Admin Client, then please open a Quarkus issue for us to investigate, thanks